# Estimation Method for Modelling Data from Scatterplot

Tags: variables, statistics, regression, scatter-plot, estimation

I have data with a relationship pattern between the dependent and independent variables like the following graph. What is the estimation method suitable for modeling it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vk9b.jpg)

Estimation method from the relationship pattern between the dependent and independent variables